# Unable to upload audio file in proper format

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-mediaplayer, firebase-storage

I am trying to upload audio fire, but it is not correctly formatted , when Iplay the downloaded URL is just hang the phone

```
  private void uploadFileToDataBase(Uri uriMain, final String type, String meta) {
    StorageMetadata metadata = new StorageMetadata.Builder()
            .setContentType(meta)
            .build();

    UserFirebase.getmStorageRef().child("Audio").child(uriMain.getLastPathSegment()).putFile(uriMain, metadata)
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                    Task<Uri> uri = taskSnapshot.getStorage().getDownloadUrl();
                    while (!uri.isComplete()) ;
                    Uri url = uri.getResult();
                    sendFirebaseMessage(String.valueOf(url), type);
                }
            });

}
```

This is how I get audio file

```
   public void MediaRecorderReady() {
    mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
    mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
    mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(AudioSavePathInDevice);
    mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
}
```

And I am playing audio like this

```
   player = new MediaPlayer();
                    player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                    player.setDataSource(context, Uri.parse(firbaseUrl);
                    player.prepare();
                    player.start();
```

Comment: Have you tried to use curly braces to your while statement instead of `;`?

Comment: yes i am uploading image with same

Comment: i have not tired with curly braces as it complete the uri first the i get url from it

Comment: i have tried to play audio directy from storage but it is not working too so while function is not the issue

Comment: here is the sample  https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/weto-d0a50.appspot.com/o/Audio%2FLLLKBAudioRecording.3gp?alt=media&token=32edd249-3434-4ce7-a51d-19e4e4789100